# Diffenrence between object mirroring through the reflection plane x = y and reflection along X-Y plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a problem to understand where so difference between does two task is:

1. Give the homogeneous 4x4 matrix describing a object mirroring/reflect along the X-Y plane.
2. Give the homogeneous 4x4 matrix describing a object mirroring/reflect along the plane described by x=y.

Isn't it the same?

The solutions say no, but why?

Solution 1:
$\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$

Solution 2:
$\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$

Sorry its maybe a dumb question, but i just can't find the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having problem with visualizing the difference between the two types of reflecting, following diagram may help you.

[image: Reflesction]